# A checked-out resource is overdue, and will be destroyed: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@437c5a2d issue tomcat 7 c3p0

Tags: connection-pooling, c3p0

we use tomcat 7 and c3p0 as a connection pool.But since starting tomcat every 3 seconds i see many warnings :
17-Jan-2023 20:35:49.259 INFO [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->z8kfltat1hfo3gq19fe7ui|2e3d1388]-AdminTaskTimer] com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool. A checked-out resource is overdue, and will be destroyed: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@7abb733e

Here is the connection pool config:
17-Jan-2023 20:39:4.647 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-2] com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource. Initializing c3p0 pool... com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource [ acquireIncrement -> 20, acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 0, connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, contextClassLoaderSource -> caller, dataSourceName -> z8kfltat1hftvt811qptc9|2e3d1388, debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> false, description -> OLTP Connection, driverClass -> oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver, extensions -> {}, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, identityToken -> z8kfltat1hftvt811qptc9|2e3d1388, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 300, initialPoolSize -> 3, jdbcUrl -> jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.0.xx:xxxx:xxxx, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, maxConnectionAge -> 0, maxIdleTime -> 30, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 30, maxPoolSize -> 500, maxStatements -> 0, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 0, minPoolSize -> 50, numHelperThreads -> 3, preferredTestQuery -> SELECT 1 FROM dual, privilegeSpawnedThreads -> false, properties -> {user=******, password=******}, propertyCycle -> 0, statementCacheNumDeferredCloseThreads -> 0, testConnectionOnCheckin -> true, testConnectionOnCheckout -> false, unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 12, userOverrides -> {}, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false ]

P.S. sorry for my english :)

I've already read every single issue posted here,tried some,but no clue.We call connection.close() in finally  for each connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `unreturnedConnectionTimeout` set to 12 seconds. The message you are seeing is due to `Connection`s not being promptly returned to the pool, triggering destruction of those `Connection`s.

Despite your protestation that you call `Connection.close()` in a `finally` block, either your uses of `Connection`s are taking longer than you expect (your database operations take more than 12 seconds), or you are leaking `Connection`s.

`c3p0` has a facility to debug apparently leaked `Connection`s. Set `debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces` to `true` (only to debug, it has a performance cost), and you will see the stack traces that checked out the `Connection`s that c3p0 times out and destroys.

If your database operations just sometimes take more than 12 seconds, just set `unreturnedConnectionTimeout` to a larger value. If you find that there's a leak, you'll see where it is to fix it.

See the docs, [here](https://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_to_debug_and_workaround_broken_clients).

Comment: Thanks Steve.But the problem is i already set unreturnedConnectionTimeout to true.This exception occurs for any connection.Could u please check my connection properties also?  I am not sure if set proper values:  maxIdleTime -> 30, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 30, maxPoolSize -> 500  We restart tomcat every night.btw

Comment: There are dozens of similar leaks shown in Jprofiler .  5:47.698  3,350 second  Unclosed collected jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.0. http-nio-8080-exec-17 [main] com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection 
5:47.771 3,350 second    Unclosed collected jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.0 http-nio-8080-exec-15 [main] com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection 
5:47.798   3,350 second  Unclosed collected jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168. b http-nio-8080-exec-19 [main] com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection

Comment: so you are leaking Connections. in your config above, unreturnedConnectionTimeout was set to 12. but it’s debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces that should be set to true. then you’ll see logging of the stack traces that opened the leaked connections.

Comment: What parameteres would you recommend as maxIdleTime, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections ,maxPoolSize ? when i play with unreturnedConnectionTimeout  and parameters above, the frequency of destroying overdue connection changes.I wonder if i did any misconfig.

Comment: I can't see why maxIdleTime, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections, maxPoolSize would much affect the frequency of destroying overdue Connections. unreturnedConnectionTimeout certainly would. I would recommend much, much longer values of maxIdleTime and maxIdleTimeExcessConnections. Connections don't go stale very quickly, and given your large range from min to max pool size, it seems like there are times when all Connections won't be in frequent use. I'd consider bringing idleConnectionTestPeriod down to 30 and maxIdleTime to 300 (or much more).

Comment: [maxIdleTimeExcessConnections](https://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#maxIdleTimeExcessConnections), if you use it (you need not) should be shorter than maxIdleTime if it's going to make any difference. But you need not set maxIdleTimeExcessConnections at all.

Comment: I will change values as u said.Thanks a lot